# Xcode could not open file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a mini tweet and working with team members using RxSwift and MVVM. But when I try to open a new file, it doesn't open. Restarting the computer and restarting the app is the same.
[image]

I'm working on the same branch as a team member, is that a problem? Why won't it open

NetworkingAPI and ViewModelType is new created file but The file color is weird

Comment: right click the file and then click "show in finder" and see if it's there. If it's in a repo just reclone the project and checkout the branch again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of reasons why that specific file went missing.

1. You might've dragged that file from somewhere into your Xcode project and you thought that it was copied properly onto your project folder and deleted it from the original source folder.
2. Merge issues.
3. Similar to #2, another team member of your project pushed the file in a wrongful way.

---

There are of course also ways to recover it.

1. Check your local machine.
2. Ask for the most updated file from your teammate.
3. Check your commits, and simply copy the whole source from there and fix it in your Xcode project by making a new file in your project folder.

I think the #3 should suffice.

Comment: So is there a way to delete the newly saved file and get a new clone?

Comment: Yes! As long as that file DOES exist in your repository. Otherwise, the #3 should help.

Answer (score 0):

You have the reference in Xcode but the files are missing.

This happened when merging and you had `.xcodeproj conflict` then someone solved it in the wrong way. Check this as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12907864/3933094

Comment: Together with team members, the master branch defines a basic pod install or folder structure. I know master branch is not good but this project is simple, so I choose this way. than What should I do then?

Comment: Maybe your team member didn't commit those files to the repo yet. Ask him to verify it again.