# . gitattributes not working

Tags: xcode, git, gitattributes

My `.gitattributes` has the following in order to diff the **XCode** project (which is plain text)

```
*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge
```

But when I diff, still showing binary file

```
# git diff MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
diff --git a/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj b/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
index xxx..xxx xxx
Binary files a/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj and b/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj differ
```

My `.gitattributes` is in the same level of `.git` folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct.  Your `.gitattributes` is saying to treat the file as binary when it comes to diffing and merging.  Take a look at this StackOverflow question, which is awfully similar to yours: [Git and pbxproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549578/git-and-pbxproj)