# pull changes from branch when deleting files

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I can't figure out the best way to do this and it has happened a few times where I mess myself up that it'd be nice to know a possible good way for this.  On master, I have our main project.  We finally got approved to use ARC in iOS and I created a new branch for that to not mess with the main working master branch.  I also took the time to delete some unneeded files in my ARCBranch.  What I want to do is use this branch for development for the next release.  I'd like to pull in the changes from master to the ARCBranch.  So I switched to ARCBranch, and did

```
git pull origin master
```

I got conflicts, some which were straightforward because I could see the code, others being changes in the pbxproj file where I cannot tell what's what.  I did see
<<< HEAD ==== >>>.  I can't tell what I need to do here.  I can't open it in Xcode, only a text editor.  I tried just deleting those <<< === >>> characters since I saw one person on SO say that you typically want both changes and that you could always do that.  This didn't work for me.  I was wondering if there is a better way to do this change.  Maybe somewhere where I can see each change by change happen?  Thanks.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1549578/212858

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you could try

```
git rebase master
```

This would apply the changes commit by commit. If there are conflicts, it would stop there, so that you can resolve them and do

```
git rebase --continue
```

to finish applying all the patches.

Answer (score 0):

It failed to auto merge so it marks the conflicting blocks of code and leaves them both so you can decide and remove one yourself.